# Converting a datetime field return nothing in php/mssql query

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to the world of PHP and MS SQL (just so you know as I am more than likely doing something simple wrong) but I am trying to convert a data time field and its running the query but only returning ,,,,,

MS SQL Query:

```
$query = "SELECT TOP(30) tbltest.MetalSourceID, tbltest.DateCreated, tbltest.UnitPrice, tbltest.HighUnitPrice, tblCurrency.Currency, tbltest2.UnitBasis FROM  tbltest INNER JOIN tbltest2 ON tbltest.MetalSourceID =     tbltest2.MetalSourceID INNER JOIN tblCurrency ON tbltest2.CurrencyID = tblCurrency.CurrencyID WHERE tbltest.MetalSourceID = '1' ORDER BY tbltest.DateCreated DESC";
```

I know the query works fine as if I remove the tbltest.DateCreated it pulls the information out that I want. But when I added back in DateCreated and use the date_format it doesn't seem to return anything but the ,,,, (that are being echo'd between each piece of data.

This leads me to believe its something I am not doing correctly with the PHP date_time function. I've read the php documentation online and other posts and tried other variables but nothing seems to be working.

PHP CODE:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){
echo $result -> MetalSourceID .",".$result -> UnitPrice .",". $result -> HighUnitPrice .",".$result -> Currency .",".$result -> UnitBasis .",". date_format($result -> DateCreated, 'd-m-Y H:i:s')."<br />";        
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all just as an update i've sorted it with the below changes, I knew it would be something simple:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){
echo $row->MetalSourceID.",".$row->DateCreated->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').",".$row->UnitPrice.",".$row->HighUnitPrice.",".$row->Currency.",".$row->UnitBasis."<br />";
}
```